# Custom Placeholderimage resize issue in magento 2

Tags: adminhtml, image, magento2.2.4, placeholder

I have added custom placeholder image in backend. But it is not resized as thumbnail image while editing the product.

**expected result**

In the place of default placeholder, my custom image should be displayed with same size of default placeholder image

[image]

**But Actual result what i get**

[image]

Please provide me a solution

1)Why my custom placeholder image not as resized like default placeholder image.

2)Then, In what size am I need to upload the custom placeholder image.